# simple layout in css

Tags: html, css, layout

I try to have a few hours own layout, but I still have a problem. I would like make: http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/1243/schemal.png

I would like that the body  was flexible. Max width page 900px. I can't cope with float and clear.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/eTEz2/

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rearranging the HTML slightly (moving all of the sidebar items to line up with one another - oneleft, oneright, twoleft etc...), I've recreated that effect, assuming you want the body to contain the floated items, and spill out below, [with this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTEz2/1/).

If that's not the effect you wanted, I would suggest you rearrange your HTML to have three columns, like below:

```
<div class="column-left"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column-right"></div>
```

And within these divs, you can have whatever elements you want, and you would only need to float the left and right columns here.

Comment: Like I said, try using the HTML format I provided after that, and simply set the properties as follows: `.column-left{float: left; width: [enter width];} .column-right{float: right; width: [enter width];}` That way, it will keep the content in line with the edges, regardless of height.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eTEz2/3/ would work? (Just need to add paddings to the columns for them to work properly)

Answer (score 0):

Try to chop it up into different partitions first: header, footer, 2 sides and 1 content. The sides consist of 3 elements again (probably divs in your case).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ></div> //top bar

<div id="left column" style="width:100px;float:left;">
   <div style="float:left; width:100px;">//left boxes
   <div style="float:left; width:100px;">
   <div style="float:left; width:100px;">
   <div style="float:left; width:100px;">
</div>

<div id="center column"  style="float:left; width:500px;">
     <div style="float:left; width:490px;"> //center box
</div>

<div id="rightcolumn" style="float:left; width:100px;">
   <div style="float:left; width:100px;">//right boxes
   <div style="float:left; width:100px;">
   <div style="float:left; width:100px;">
   <div style="float:left; width:100px;">
</div>
```

you can also use the css property height:190px; to set various heights. hope this helps you out.